# AngularJS: How to refresh parent controller

Tags: angularjs

When the index.html page is rendered my ApplicationController will be called. When I login (login success)I want to refresh my ApplicationController. How to do it?

I have defined below Controllers in my application.

1)Login

```
   angular.module('aclf').controller('LoginController', LoginController);
    // The $inject property is an array of service names to inject.
    LoginController.$inject = [ '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
            'FlashService' ];
    function LoginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
        var loginController = this;

        loginController.login = login;

        (function initController() {
            // reset login status
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
        })();

        function login() {
            loginController.dataLoading = true;
            AuthenticationService.Login(loginController.username,
                    loginController.password, function(response) {
                        if (response.username === loginController.username) {
                            console.log(response.authToken);
                            AuthenticationService.SetCurrentUser(
                                    loginController.username,
                                    response.authToken, true);
                            $location.path('/home');
                        } else {
                            FlashService.Error(response.message);
                            loginController.dataLoading = false;
                        }
                    });
        }
        ;
    }
```

2)ApplicationCotroller

```
angular.module('aclf').controller('ApplicationController',
            function($scope,$rootScope) {
                $scope.currentUser = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
                console.log('Inside ApplicationController');
            })
```

3)HomeController- When home controller rendered I want to refresh the  portion, since it contains currentUser.

```
/**
     * Home Controller
     */

    angular.module('aclf').controller('HomeController', HomeController);
    // The $inject property is an array of service names to inject.
    HomeController.$inject = [ 'UserService', '$rootScope' ];
    function HomeController(UserService, $rootScope) {
        var homeController = this;

        homeController.user = null;


        initController();

        function initController() {
            loadCurrentUser();

        }

        function loadCurrentUser() {
            UserService.GetByUsername($rootScope.globals.currentUser.username)
                    .then(function(user) {
                        homeController.user = user;
                    });
        }
    }
```

4)This is my index.html page
Here I have defined my ApplicationController on body part. This needs to be refreshed at least after login and logout

```
<body data-ng-controller="ApplicationController">


    <!-- TOPBAR START -->
    <div id="layout-topbar" data-ng-show="currentUser">
        <ul id="top-menu">
            <li>
                <span class="Fs22 FontRobotoLight">Welcome {{currentUser.username}} </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- TOPBAR END -->
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="wrapperIndent">

                <div id="layout-menu-cover" class="Animated05 ps-container">
                    <div class="ps-scrollbar-x-rail" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px;">
                        <div class="ps-scrollbar-x" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ps-scrollbar-y-rail" style="top: 0px; right: 3px;">
                        <div class="ps-scrollbar-y" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="layout-portlets-cover">
                    <div class="Container96 Fnone MarAuto">

                        <div class="Container100">
                            <div class="ContainerIndent">
                                <div class="EmptyBox10"></div>
                                <div
                                        data-ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }"
                                        data-ng-if="flash" data-ng-bind="flash.message"></div>
                                <div data-ng-view></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- footer -->
                        <div class="Container100">
                            <div class="ContainerIndent TexAlCenter Fs14">
                                Angular | All Rights Reserved.</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

PS: I am very new to AngularJS

Comment: But you have declared olny one controller on you html page.Where did you declare the other controllers(HomeController and LoginController)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with reload page stuff. But it was not working.

I removed Application Controller and used

```
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
                controller : 'HomeController',
                templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
                controllerAs : 'homeController',
                leftNav : 'partials/left-nav-main.html',
                topNav: 'partials/top-nav.html'
    })

.when('/login', {
            controller : 'LoginController',
            templateUrl : 'partials/login.html',
            controllerAs : 'loginController'
        })
```

Here the templateUrl property in the route definition references the view template that is loaded in the ng-view directive of the div element. I tried to simulate something similar to what Angular does for our left
and top navigation.
The value of the topNav property is used to load the top navigation view in the topnav div element ("id = top-nav") using the ng-include directive. We do the same for left navigation too. The ng-if directive in the left-nav section is used to hide left navigation if the current route configuration does not define the leftNav property.

The last part of this integration is setting up the currentRoute property and
binding it to ng-include. Angular sets up the ng-view template using the route configuration templateUrl property, but it does not know or care about the topNav and leftNav properties that we have added. We need to write some custom code that binds the navigation URLs with the respective ng-includes directives.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, previous) {
$scope.currentRoute = current;
});
```

Here is my index.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top top-navbar">
<!--Existing html-->
<div id="top-nav-container" class="second-top-nav">
<div id="top-nav" ng-include="currentRoute.topNav"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="content-container" class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2 left-nav-bar"
ng-if="currentRoute.leftNav">
<div id="left-nav" ng-include="currentRoute.leftNav"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
<div id="page-content" ng-view></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now the left-nav and top-nav appears only in home page and does not appear in login page.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think the best practice is to reload the entire page:

If you are using [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

`$state.reload();`

If you use another router

`$route.reload();`